# Ordering list by shared value of property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects with field UserID, Property:

I would like to order the list by most shared property value. So if every user has Property= "Popular", that should come up first.  If everyone but one user has Property="Second" that should come up second in list...
even if its only used once for each user.

I would do distinct() on each possible Property and but that doesnt seem efficient with many possible Property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a grouping on `Property`, order the groups by the number of counts in each group and then flatten the list again using `SelectMany()`:

```
var items = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Property)
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                  .SelectMany(g => g);
                  .ToList();
```

From your question its not quite clear to me whether you want duplicates to show up or not and if you are at all interested in the `UserID`. If not, you can just select the keys of the groups to give you a `List<string>` of unique Property values in the desired order:

```
var props = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Property)
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                  .Select(g => g.Key);
                  .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

It seems like this would be more what you are actually are looking for - groups are are ordered by the number of unique users that have a given property.

```
var props = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Property)
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Select(x=> x.UserID)
                                           .Distinct()
                                           .Count())
                  .Select(g => g.Key);
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: but this orders by total frequency of property, not by unique user. ??

Comment: You should clarify your question then. How would you like to order your list items and what should be returned?

Comment: Updated answer - *I think* this is what you are looking for.

Comment: i think my question was clear, i even said i was going to use Distinct but wondered about doing different. Anyway, seems to work thanks.